# call javascript function from another javascript function on confirmation

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am showing a Confirmation modal popup where user can either select yes or no and when user clicks yes i want to show another modal popup 
this is my script for confirmation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModalConfirm(message, header, url) {
        $(<%= myModal.ClientID%>).modal('show');
        $('#lblMasterMessage').html(header);
        $('#lblMasterbodyMessage').html(message);
        $('#<%= BtnYes.ClientID %>').attr('onclick', "$('#myModal').modal('hide');setTimeout(function(){" + $(sender).prop('href') + "}, 50);");
        $(<%= myModal.ClientID%>).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            if (url != '') {
                window.location = url;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

and this is the moadal popup which i want to show after the above popup is shown

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal(message, header, url) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#lblMasterMessage').html(header);
        $('#lblMasterbodyMessage').html(message);
        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            if (url != '') {
                window.location = url;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: make your code available online